# my pc Hang on "cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully"

Tags: 16.04

I've looked at a couple methods but this is all new territory for me. Workflow: I boot up my machine, then I'm asked for my pass phrase, I successfully enter it and I get the "cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully". After that the system hangs. I don't any functionality, no ctrl+alt+f1

Answer (score 5):

For me it was missing nvidia drivers. Start up in recovery mode and select resume boot after unlocking your drive in the shell and you should be able to get past the "[drive] set up successfully" screen. From there you should install drivers for any discrete video cards you have. Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: You can install the latest NVIDIA drivers like in this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/968071/336238